# Facebook Javascript SDK Authentication Persistence?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the following Facebook Client SDK inorder to authenticate a user without a page refresh (works great)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

The problem I have is I want to store some data along with that user in a local database.  SO if the user authenticates himself it would pull back his given data.

I'v seen access tokens but that isn't a permant link to the user.  What exactly do I need to check server side as well to guarantee the user and what would I need to store in my DB (account table)?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the user [facebook id](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) and check each time if he is present in the database or he is a new one.

Comment: Are you saying pass the UserID from the client to the server?  How would that guarantee a legitimate request?

Comment: By parsing and validating the `signed_request` parameter.